# How to account for a fixed nav when using scrollIntoView() with smooth scrolling enabled?

Tags: javascript, css

So I haven't been able to find a way to use `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})` while still accounting for a fixed nav. The scroll works great, but the fixed nav is always covering over the header I'm trying to scroll to. I've looked around online and found some other solutions. But I've yet to find one that includes the smooth scrolling behavior. I want to avoid having an abrupt jump to the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid this behaviour, instead of having a fixed header, you can just make the header statically positioned and place it above a `div` that *does* scroll.

```js
function doIt() {
  const header = document.getElementById("header1");
  header.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: none;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

nav {
  height: 100pt;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

section#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    This is a nav bar.
    <a href="#" onclick="doIt()">go to header1</a>
  </nav>
  <section id="content">
    <h1 id="header1">
      This is a header.
    </h1>
    <p>
      This is some text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam decore labore accumsan no. Ad perfecto inciderint eum, quaeque reprimique an sea. Et omnis ridens option vim, ex vix dico oblique repudiandae, idque accommodare ut usu. Erant consequat intellegam vis
      id, dolorum ancillae mandamus mel eu. Quo elit solum ridens ad, nibh docendi recusabo eu qui. Dolorem quaestio pri ea, etiam aeterno vim ei. Te oporteat maiestatis constituam sea, mea euripidis vulputate id. Mea populo persequeris instructior ea.
      Ut graecis cotidieque pri.</p>
    <h1 id="header2">
      This is another header.
    </h1>
    <p>
      Quo cu iriure conceptam, inani molestiae usu te, cum et dolorum denique epicuri. Adhuc iusto vel ei, eos ex efficiantur theophrastus, tale sanctus erroribus eos cu. Mollis regione accusam nam ex. Te vim dolorem qualisque, ex per odio putent intellegat,
      et percipitur liberavisse nec. Usu porro causae ne, no possim definiebas his. Wisi utroque has an. An qui evertitur elaboraret suscipiantur, eam adipisci conceptam eu, graeco nusquam inimicus ut usu. Officiis molestiae ullamcorper vis eu, no laudem
      graeci contentiones per, id salutandi dissentiunt cum. An eam natum alterum, fugit paulo ad his. Intellegebat definitiones ex sed, ea per suas tincidunt, mei in viderer partiendo conclusionemque. Ullum appetere in nec, stet vivendo consetetur eu
      eos.
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Contrast this with a version with a fixed nav bar:

```js
function doIt() {
  const header = document.getElementById("header1");
  header.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

```css
nav {
  height: 100pt;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

section#content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    This is a nav bar.
    <a href="#" onclick="doIt()">go to header1</a>
  </nav>
  <section id="content">
    <h1 id="header1">
      This is a header.
    </h1>
    <p>
      This is some text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nam decore labore accumsan no. Ad perfecto inciderint eum, quaeque reprimique an sea. Et omnis ridens option vim, ex vix dico oblique repudiandae, idque accommodare ut usu. Erant consequat intellegam vis
      id, dolorum ancillae mandamus mel eu. Quo elit solum ridens ad, nibh docendi recusabo eu qui. Dolorem quaestio pri ea, etiam aeterno vim ei. Te oporteat maiestatis constituam sea, mea euripidis vulputate id. Mea populo persequeris instructior ea.
      Ut graecis cotidieque pri.</p>
    <h1 id="header2">
      This is another header.
    </h1>
    <p>
      Quo cu iriure conceptam, inani molestiae usu te, cum et dolorum denique epicuri. Adhuc iusto vel ei, eos ex efficiantur theophrastus, tale sanctus erroribus eos cu. Mollis regione accusam nam ex. Te vim dolorem qualisque, ex per odio putent intellegat,
      et percipitur liberavisse nec. Usu porro causae ne, no possim definiebas his. Wisi utroque has an. An qui evertitur elaboraret suscipiantur, eam adipisci conceptam eu, graeco nusquam inimicus ut usu. Officiis molestiae ullamcorper vis eu, no laudem
      graeci contentiones per, id salutandi dissentiunt cum. An eam natum alterum, fugit paulo ad his. Intellegebat definitiones ex sed, ea per suas tincidunt, mei in viderer partiendo conclusionemque. Ullum appetere in nec, stet vivendo consetetur eu
      eos.
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

In Firefox at least, this version also seems to work. That is, you can also get away with simply inserting a padding or a margin at the top of your container. However, this is probably less reliable.

Answer (score -1):

When I use a fixed header I have the same height as the fixed header on the body. So if the navbar is 64px high I use 64px padding-top on the body.

```
.navbar {
    height: 64px;
}

body {
    padding-top: 64px;
}
```

Should be easy to sort it out.

Comment: This only takes care of the header not covering important content when the page is scrolled to top, but `scrollIntoView` scrolls the element into view. the body padding has no influence on the space between the upper boundary of the viewport and the element.